# Deadlock occurring in a Non Clustered Column store Index ( MS SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, deadlock

I have created Non Clustered Column store index for one of my table (For Example :ClientData is the table name) which contains about 100 columns and more than 2 million rows. I noticed multiple Dead locks after creating column store indexes .
While creating the index , i have some SQL jobs which should run continuously, and those SQL Jobs contains multiple transactions and these transactions are using same table (For Example :ClientData is the table name ) to insert/delete/update the records . When i run the sql query to check the locked objects, i noticed SQL query is returning locked Object name along with Transaction name and some other columns in a result set.  When i checked the transaction name from result set, i noticed same transactions which are used in Stored procedure to run SQL job .

Will transaction causes any issues ?
If Issues with Transactions from Continuously running SQL JOB, How do i avoid dead locks With out stopping my SQL JOB
Could anyone help me on this ?

I have used below query to check locked objects

```
SELECT  L.request_session_id AS SPID, 
DB_NAME(L.resource_database_id) AS DatabaseName,
O.Name AS LockedObjectName, 
P.object_id AS LockedObjectId, 
L.resource_type AS LockedResource, 
L.request_mode AS LockType,
ST.text AS SqlStatementText,
ES.login_name AS LoginName,
ES.host_name AS HostName,
TST.is_user_transaction as IsUserTransaction,
AT.name as TransactionName,
CN.auth_scheme as AuthenticationMethod
FROM    sys.dm_tran_locks L
JOIN sys.partitions P ON P.hobt_id = L.resource_associated_entity_id
JOIN sys.objects O ON O.object_id = P.object_id
JOIN sys.dm_exec_sessions ES ON ES.session_id = L.request_session_id
JOIN sys.dm_tran_session_transactions TST ON ES.session_id = TST.session_id
JOIN sys.dm_tran_active_transactions AT ON TST.transaction_id = AT.transaction_id
JOIN sys.dm_exec_connections CN ON CN.session_id = ES.session_id
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(CN.most_recent_sql_handle) AS ST
WHERE   resource_database_id = db_id()
ORDER BY L.request_session_id
```

Thanks,
Shankar

Comment: Read any article about best practices for avoiding deadlocks. Your question is vague.

Comment: check this article:  https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2517/using-a-clustered-index-to-solve-a-sql-server-deadlock-issue/